# react-table: multiple levels of sub-columns

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Is it possible to divide a **sub-column** into another set of **sub-columns** in the *react-table*? Like so:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Column 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
         Sub-column 1              |           Sub-column 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub-sub-col 11  |  Sub-sub-col 12  | Sub-sub-col 21  |  Sub-sub-col 22 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is what I tried with no success:

```
[
     Header: 'Column 1',
     columns: [
          {
               Header: 'Sub-column 1',
               columns: [
                    {
                         Header: 'Sub-sub-column 11',
                         accessor: 'accessor1'
                    },
                    {
                         Header: 'Sub-sub-column 12',
                         accessor: 'accessor1'
                    }
               ]
          }
     ]
]
```

The problem is that it renders only **Column 1** and its **Sub-column 1** and none of **Sub-sub-columns**. So the result looks like:

```
                                    Column 1
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
             Sub-column 1              |           Sub-column 2
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Am I encountering the limitation of react-table or doing something wrong?
If this is a limitation, please advise a workaround or any solutions that work for this case.

> "react-table": "^6.11.5"

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using the latest version of react table. The older version used to support only two levels of column headers. This has been corrected in the latest versions , and they allow you to add columns recursively.

Please see this issue for more details https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/1068